# In how many ways can ten people be seated in a row so that a certain two of them are not next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

What I'm thinking: Find total ways that the ten people can be seated, which is 10!.

Then I take that number and subtract the ways the these two people would be seated next to each other. I do this by treating these two people as a single space, which leaves the eight other students plus that space consisting of the two. This would mean 9!

Then, 10! - 9! = 3265920 ways for the ten people to be seated so that a certain to are not next to each other.

Comment: Your approach is correct except for one detail: the two people seated next to each other can be arranged in two (left/right) ways.

Comment: Good catch. So, what I've done is 10! - (9!)(2!) = 2903040. Looks good to me as of right now.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of thinking is.  You can freely position 9 people (including one of the special two), therefore $9!$.  However the remaining one cannot sit next to the other special person, so only 8 possible positions.  Overall $8 \times 9!$

Answer (score 1):

Call the two special people $A$ and $B$.  There are nine seats where the "left" one can sit and the right next to him.  There are two such cases $AB$ and $BA$.  For each of these conditions there are 8 remaining slots that can be filled by the remaining $8$ folk arbitrarily.

Thus:  $9 \cdot 2 \cdot 8! = 725,760$

The total number of ways the chosen two people do *not* sit next to each other is $10! - 9 \cdot 2 \cdot 8! = 2,903,040$.

Comment: So this would be the solution to all cases where these two people sit next to each other, correct? This number is then subtracted from 10! to get all cases where these two people are not next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The best
way to solve this is take the 2 special people as a separate unit. Arrange the 8 other people in a row i.e. 8!. Since this is a linear arrangement, the number of gaps between the 8 already seated people will be 9. To select 2 gaps from 9 gaps we'll use 9C2 for A and B and multiply by 2! for arranging A and B (basically 9P2).
So, the overall answer is 8!×9c2×2!
Thank you.